# Rails 6.0.3.1 ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `hero_id`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models:

```
User
Hero
HeroSkin

Hero Skin belongs to :hero
Hero has_many :hero_skins
```

Hero Skin and Hero belong to "many" :users

So in my user model I have:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :heroes
has_and_belongs_to_many :hero_skins
```

And then in my hero and heroskin model I have:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

However, in rails console, when I try to create a skin and associate the 'skin' with the 'hero' it says "Can't write unknown attribute, hero_id"

[image]

Also, how would I go about giving my "users" skins and "heroes"

Also, for some reason, rails keeps pluralizing "heroes" as "heros" and it's ruining a lot of stuff, can I fix this somehow?

Comment: "Can't write unknown attribute, hero_id" I fixed this issue, I renamed the column reference as it was plural and should have been singular...

Comment: Please remove the image and replace it with the text of the message, copied, then pasted into the question, formatted appropriately. See "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)" for more information.